# How to use ‘autocmd’ and ‘augroup’ with ‘map {lhs} {rhs}’ in a vimrc file?

Tags: vim, dictionary, editor, text-editor

Why does the following run-time configuration settings for **Vim** *(text editor)* doesn't work properly?

```
autocmd colorscheme default map <F2> :colorscheme elflord<CR>
autocmd colorscheme elflord map <F2> :colorscheme default<CR>
```

---

```
autocmd! colorscheme default map <F2> :colorscheme elflord<CR>
autocmd! colorscheme elflord map <F2> :colorscheme default<CR>
```

---

```
augroup CScheme
  autocmd!
  autocmd colorscheme default map <F2> :colorscheme elflord<CR>
  autocmd colorscheme elflord map <F2> :colorscheme default<CR>
augroup END
```

All of those settings above remapped the key *<F2>* into the string *"<F2>"*, and I can see it clearly when I press the remapped key while I'm in **Insert** mode. What is the right syntax for `autocmd` and `augroup` with `map {lhs} {rhs}` in Vim?

Comment: What I'm trying is to remap the key _<F2>_ into `:colorscheme elflord<CR>` if the current `colorscheme` is _default_ and to remap the _<F2>_ into `:colorscheme default<CR>` if the `colorscheme` is _elflord_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:map` command combines normal, visual+select, and operator-pending modes. If you want *all* modes, you need to issue a separate `:map!` (with `!`) for insert and command-line modes. See `:help map-modes`. So, your troubleshooting attempt in *insert mode* is invalid.

But there's another problem: In the `:autocmd`, the `{pat}` file pattern is the current buffer's filename, not the colorscheme name. You can see this with the following autocmd:

```
:autocmd ColorScheme * echomsg "file is" expand('<afile>')
```

This will **not** print the colorscheme name, but the current buffer's name. It would be nice to have the `ColorScheme` event work on the scheme name, but it's not currently implemented this way. Therefore, your clever remapping scheme won't work.

Instead, define a single `:autocmd ColorScheme *`, and use a conditional (on the `g:colors_name` variable, which contains the current colorscheme name) to toggle / move through the colorschemes, or just use the conditional inside the mapping, like this:

```
:nnoremap <F2> :execute 'colorscheme' (g:colors_name ==# 'default' ? 'elflord' : 'default')<CR>
```

---

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: I know it. And of course, I've already tested the runtime configuration settings on the question above in **Normal** mode a.k.a. command mode.

Comment: So that entire part was somewhat misleading, since you didn't state what does not work. Anyway, I think I've found the problem; see my edit.

Comment: Oh sorry.. Could you please write a complete runtime configuration settings regarding to my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998510/how-to-use-autocmd-and-augroup-with-map-lhs-rhs-in-a-vimrc-file#comment28069661_18998510

Comment: That's better done dynamically in the mapping; you then don't need any `:autocmd`! I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Can you refer links to tutorials for learning such as the `g:colors_name` variable? I want to know what's `g:`.

Comment: `g:` is just the prefix for **global** variables; the var itself is a convention; each colorscheme script is supposed to set it. Your first instinct should be to reach for the excellent built-in help: `:help g:colors_name` alreadys gives you some context.

Comment: Can I ask you why the following remap doesn't work? `:noremap <F2> :colorscheme (g:colors_name ==# 'default' ? 'elflord' : 'default')<CR>`

Comment: Vim's evaluation rules are different. You need `:execute` to get the variable / conditional evaluated.